# Unable to call Wcf Post Method From Ionic 3

Tags: c#, wcf, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am requesting wcf post method from ionic, but i am getting error

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

My WCF Post method is,

```
  public Stream GetMonthWiseAttendance(InputMonthwise input)
        {
            var SerializeObject = new JavaScriptSerializer();    
            var temp = context.MobAttendMonthWiseStudentAttaindance(input.StudentMainId, input.InstituteId, input.Yearid).ToList();
            string jsonClient = SerializeObject.Serialize(temp);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
                "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With,Accept");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient));
       }
```

My Ionic code is

```
callPost()  
 { 
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
   let data=JSON.stringify({userName:'Rameshwar',InstituteId:1191,Yearid:135,StudentMainId:135 });

      this.http.post("myUrl"  ,data, { headers: headers }   )
           .subscribe(res => 
                          {               
                              alert("success "+JSON.stringify(res));
                          },
                          (err) => 
                          {
                              alert('ERRROR '+JSON.stringify(err));
                           });
  }
```

With this ionic code i am able to call post method of php but calling wcf method i got error . I am also able to call Get method of Wcf  with same header to response

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =
                "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With,Accept");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient));
```

I have also checked this wcf post request with Postman Rest client. I am getting response well from rest client/postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in Ionic Code, there is no need to stringfy post data, ionic internally manage it.

```
let data=JSON.stringify({userName:'Rameshwar',InstituteId:1191,Yearid:135,StudentMainId:135 });
```

Change To,

```
let data={userName:'Rameshwar',InstituteId:1191,Yearid:135,StudentMainId:135 };
```

Hope this will work.